# Is there a way to access global variables inside .then() in Nightmare

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, json, nightmare

I have a repetitive function I would like to automate using NightmareJs. The task, in this case, is to open google.com and enter search text on the search bar. The site address and the text to search are both provided from a JSON file, which I have required on the global scope. But once I initiate a .then() instance, I am unable to access data from the global scope. How do I access data from the global scope under a .then() instance?

So far, I have created a Nightmare instance that looks as follows:

NightmareJs code:

```
var Nightmare = require('nightmare');
var nightmare = Nightmare({
    show:true
});
var dummy = require('./dummy.json')

nightmare
.goto(dummy[0].searchOn)
.evaluate(()=>{
    return document.querySelector('html').innerHTML
})
.then(()=>{
    return nightmare
    .insert('.gLFyf',dummy[0].searchText)
})
```

JSON code:

```
[
    {
        "searchOn": "https://www.google.com",
        "searchText": "I love google"
    }
]
```

I expected to be able to insert the search text (under searchText) from the JSON file on the search bar on Google. Please advise. Thanks

**PS:** Yes, I do understand there is a simpler way to do this by changing where I place .insert() as follows:

```
nightmare
.goto(dummy[0].searchOn)
.insert('.gLFyf', dummy[0].searchText)
.then()
```

But I would like to know how to do this for future reference, as I have encountered this problem several times before.

Comment: It's unclear what the problem is. Are you referring to `dummy` as 'global scope'? It's not global scope. And nothing prevents it from being available in `then` callback. Is there error message?